# Missing linux headers during ATI driver installation

Tags: linux, kernel, fglrx

I've updated the kernel on my Linux Mint following [this tutorial](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/07/install-linux-kernel-35-from-ppa-on.html). But now, when I try to install the latest fglrx, I'm getting this error:

> Check if system has the tools required for installation.
>   fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.5.0-030500-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
>   One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
>   Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
>   Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.

I tried to run `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, but it says it's already the latest version. Any help?

Comment: The package manager seems to be saying that the headers should be there.  Is it possible that something has trashed the headers directory?  Maybe try forcing a reinstall of the headers to make sure they're present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than an answer, I will give you some questions :). Are you sure that you have booted into your new kernel? What is the output of `uname -a`? What are the contents of `/lib/modules/` ?

My guess is that you have simply not loaded your new kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer helped me to figure it out by myself, I was missing symbolic link `/lib/modules/3.5.0-030500-generic/build` linking to `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-030500-generic`

Comment: I have the same issue. This is the list of all `version.h` files that I have in my Fedora 20 desktop. 
`/usr/src/kernels/3.12.9-301.fc20.x86_64/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h`  `/usr/src/kernels/3.12.9-301.fc20.x86_64/include/xen/interface/version.h`  `/usr/src/kernels/3.12.9-301.fc20.x86_64/include/config/arch/want/compat/ipc/parse/version.h`  `/usr/src/kernels/3.12.9-301.fc20.x86_64/include/uapi/linux/dvb/version.h`  `/usr/include/alsa/version.h`  `/usr/include/linux/dvb/version.h`  `/usr/include/linux/version.h`

What shall I do?

Comment: @noufal please post a new question explaining your issue. The issue here was that the OP had not booted into their new kernel.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the installer/driver only works with kernels up to 3.4 - "Automated installer and Display Drivers for Xorg 6.9 to Xserver 1.12 and Kernel version up to 3.4" from [amd website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64). For me with a later kernel (3.8.0-33) it didn't reject the kernel version but fails and can't find `/lib/modules/3.8.0-33-generic/build/include/linux/version.h` - `apt-file` tells me no such file exists.